# Why does that equal to the first integer from the array?

Tags: c, arrays

I dont understand how typecasting an array into char* works.

```
int array[9] = {42, 5, 23, 82, 127, 21, 324, 3, 8};
*p = *((char*)array);
printf("1: %d\n", *p);
```

The result is "1: 42" and if I change it to `array + 4`, the result is "1: 5". Why is that?

Comment: When you increase the address of an integer array by 4  you basically just access the next integer in there, for the cases where the size of an int is 4 Bytes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you could add what behaviour you would expect.

Comment: Are you aware that downcasting a pointer to an `int` value to `char` may yield unexpected results, e. g. if the integer is > 255? That's just bad style here.

Comment: Are you aware of integer representation in little endian order?

Comment: Helpful start into the subject: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic I also strongly recommend to learn about pointers in general **before** messing with them...

Comment: What is `p`? Provide a [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question consists of 2 parts:

> Why does that equal to the first integer from the array?

```
int array[9] = {42, 5, 23, 82, 127, 21, 324, 3, 8};
*p = *((char*)array);
printf("1: %d\n", *p);
```

You have an array of integers:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--- ... ---+-----------+
|    42     |      5    |     23    |           |       8   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--- ... ---+-----------+
```

If you look at it bytewise it looks like this (assuming little endian):

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--  ... ---+--+--+--+--+
|42| 0| 0| 0| 5| 0| 0| 0|           | 8| 0| 0| 0|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--- ... ---+--+--+--+--+
 ^
 |
 p points here.
```

In a little endian layout the lowest 8 bits of an integer are located on the first byte of the integer.
This means a pointer to that address will result in the MSB. If your integer value is small enough to fit into 8 bits, the value of `*p` will be same as `array[0]`

The second part is

> if I change it to array + 4, the result is "1: 5". Why is that?

What is missing here is that you add 4 to `p`, not to `array`. Or maybe you add 4 to `(char*)array`. If you add 4 to array you would add 4*sizeof(array) bytes which is not the case.

The details about pointer arithmetics are already addressed in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

`array` is an array of int and in your case integers take 4 bytes in memory.

That is why `array` points to the first element of the array, while  `array + 4` points to the second element (the following 4 bytes in memory).